# include and header php advice

Tags: php, mysql, html, dynamic

im building my first dynamic site. i have an index.php that based on whether the following session variable is true or false

```
if($_SESSION['loggedIn'])
{   
include 'logged-in/logged-in.php';
}
else{
include 'not-logged-in/not-logged-in.php';
}
```

the not-logged-in.php displays some forms so you can either login or register this calls a function within an included php file. if the login() function validates via  login via mysql it sets

```
$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = 1;
header("Location: ../index.php");
```

i however get this error...

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /***/index.php:8) in /***/not-logged-in/not-logged-in.php on line 5

sorry i '*' out the url to keep my project private.
i come from a simple graphics programming background and so this is all new to me. any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show us the contents of  //not-logged-in/not-logged-in.php please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979341/warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by) and/or any of the following: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+modify+header+information+-+headers+already+sent

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by having something output to the browser, either with echo, print, etc. before you call the `header()`.

Personally I wouldn't use a session variable to store whether the user is logged in or not because you may want to disable a user, and if they're already logged in they will still have access until their session expires. I like to store the username and hashed password in the session and then re-run the login procedure, using these details, for each page.

Comment: i see, if i am using echo in my not-logged-in.php to output the html with the login and register forms, how would you suggest i change my workflow?

Comment: `header()` needs to be called before there is any output. It's possible that you just have a space before `<?php` somewhere. There error says that you need to check line 8 of index.php

Comment: even if header is inside an included php file? seporate from the php file that echo'd my html forms

Answer (score 1):

this error happens when you're trying to send an http header (like the Location in you code) *after* there is some kind of output. Check your code and verify your are not sending intentionally any output before sending this header (or even the session_start()). also, if you're using the php closing tags, be sure to not have a single space or newline after it, because it counts as output